# IPsecVPN + PPP over ssh routing problem

Tags: ppp, ipsec

I have two Debian hosts A and B. On A, I start IPsec VPN and my VPN clients can connect to it. In the same time, I start a PPP over ssh between A and B. So on host A, I can see ppp0 as the new Iface created by the PPP session.

My plan is to have all the VPN clients connects to host A via IPsec. And then all the IP traffic from VPN clients to internet should go through ppp0. In the other word, I want to use host B as a proxy between my VPN network and the outside world and host A as the VPN gateway. However, once I add the ppp0 as the default gateway, all my VPN clients' link drop. The ssh between A and B still alive though. Here is the detailed information.

**Step 1. start ppp over ssh.**

Here is the route table right after step 1:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.23.191.253  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.8.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
123.58.217.XX   172.23.191.253  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.23.176.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.42.253  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
```

**Step 2. add ppp0 as the default Iface**

Then I from host B to ssh login to host A and print the route table. It looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         172.23.191.253  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.8.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
123.58.217.XX   172.23.191.253  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.23.176.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

You can see that ppp1, which represents my IPsec client connected earlier is dropped. Host A has a public IP as 8.129.X.X and a private IP 172.23.191.254. After **Step 2**, I can not ping 8.129.X.X from outside. However, in the same time, inside host A, I can ping everywhere. I assume all the IP packet to internet should be sent to ppp0. It seems to be working in that way, since from host A I can ping INTERNET websites. But how to fix the IPsec link dropping problem and the problem that I can not ping host A from internet?

Comment: IPsec is over PPP? an uncommon configuration already that you should provide.

Comment: Not IPsec over PPP, host A has an IPsec setup to accept VPN client to connect to it. In the same time, host A setups a PPP over ssh to host B. So host A has two things going on in the same time, IPsev VPN and PPP over ssh. The former is for mobile clients to connect the latter is to establish a secure communication link between host A and B.